# SQL to only show records that are available (3 tables)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a web system for my University placement, and am having real trouble with the most important SQL query. I have 3 tables:

host_families (host_id, name, address, etc.)

groups (group_id, no_of_students, arrival_date, departure_date)

The aim of the system is to allocate students, from a particular group, to a particular host family. these allocations are saved in the following table:

allocations (group_id, host_id, no_of_students)

I have already managed to write the code for viewing the allocations of a particular group:

```
SELECT * from host_families, groups
INNER JOIN allocations
WHERE groups.group_id = allocations.group_id
AND host_families.host_id = allocations.host_id
AND groups.group_id = '$id'"
```

The massive problem I have is that when I allocate a host family to a group that is arriving say on '2017-06-01' for 1 week, that host family should not appear on the allocate section for another group that is arriving the next day, as he / she would be unavailable.

I have tried using the NO EXIST function but this removes the host_family from entirely even if the group was 2 weeks after (and therefore available again)

In PHP I display available host families using a while loop:

```
While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Host_qry_result)){
// table
}
```

Please help me to form a search query for my host family table which only shows host families that are available, i.e. have not been allocated to a group which lay within the arrival and departure date of the group you're searching from.

Many many thanks!

Currently after exhausting options I have returned my query to the simplest form of

```
SELECt * from host_families
```

Comment: You could have a flagged that check if the host fam is available.... when u user a group to that host fam then update the flag as well, then query host fams based on flags

Comment: basicly you have to get all the allocation in given time range and filter out those results - subquery will most likely be needed here to filter out the data. @MasivuyeCokile flag wont help you for time range problem.

Answer (score 0):

To sum things up, what you want your query to return is :

- All the host families
- Without the families that already host a group for a given date

The simplest approach for that problem is to get the subset of "busy" families, then substract it from the set containing all the families. You can do that with a sub-query, and the use of `NOT IN`.

I haven't tested the following query, but it should solve your problem :

```
SELECT *
FROM host_families
WHERE host_id NOT IN (
    -- Busy host families
    SELECT DISTINCT h2.host_id
    FROM host_families AS h2
        JOIN allocations AS a ON a.host_id = h2.host_id
        JOIN groups AS g ON g.group_id = a.group_id
    WHERE g.arrival_date <= CURDATE()
        AND g.departure_date >= CURDATE()
)
```

Note that you will likely want to replace `CURDATE()` with a given date, provided through your PHP code. I'll let you change the query above accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Kevin it almost works! Your summary is exactly what I'm after, with the SQL you provided host families do not appear when they are already allocated within a group, and do not appear when I try to allocate to another group with the same arrival / departure. But when i add host family "Bob' to a group arriving on '2017-06-01' until '2017-06-08', he is available on another group arriving on '2017-06-06', when he should only be available from '2017-06-09' (day after current group leaves), if this makes sense?

Comment: It's unclear in your comment whether your problem is still related to that SQL query, or whether it has to do with how your data is used in your PHP code. If the former, you may want to precise what your use case is, and how exactly the data is expected to be used. If the latter, it is better that you ask a different question since it is a different problem than what is presented in your question here.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote sql statements but this may help you move on.

```
SELECT .... FROM
WHERE .... AND host_families.host_id NOT IN
(select a.host_id from allocation a INNER JOIN groups g USING (group_id) where 
g.departure_date > (select arrival_date from groups where group_id = '$id'))
```

It is based on your query (those ....). The thing is I'm not sure if you can use subqueries in subqueries.

Comment: SELECT * FROM host_families, groups
WHERE groups.group_id AND host_families.host_id NOT IN
(select a.host_id from allocations a INNER JOIN groups g USING (group_id) where 
g.departure_date >= (select arrival_date from groups where group_id = '$id'))    -- This seems to work however is returning multiple host families per search, also distinct isn't working, any ideas why or if my adapted SQL is correct?/ Many thanks

Comment: you are missing join there so it selects every family and every group so for every family and lists all the groups and for all the groups it lists all the families. Thats why you have multiple ids there ... or you are just missing filter in `groups.group_id = '$id' AND `